# why edit the password not showing on new Key store creation in Android studio(flutter app)?

Tags: android, flutter, keystore

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iaoq2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjB5a.png)

how to edit password here?

Need to generate keystore for flutter app, but stucking here.

getting validation when I click OK without entering the password.

(steps: android studio -> build -> generate signed bundle id/apk -> next-> create new)

Comment: Please select path where you want to store your keystore then fields should be enabled. if not please update android studio to latest stable version and try again.